# Is there a safe way to protect the content of a route in nuxtjs?

Tags: security, authentication, nuxt.js

I'm currently experimenting with nuxtjs and authenticating users which seems to work pretty well. But I have security concerns about the content of views which require authentication.

I would like to explain my problem with an exapmle from their website: https://nuxtjs.org/examples/auth-routes/

Going to the /secret route in the example-appication I get a pretty error-page indicating that I am not authenticated which is quite nice BUT I can just search for the string "Super secret page" in one of the sites-scripts in the dev-console in chrome to find the content of the so called "Super secret page" which doesn't seem very secret at all.

To clarify: I want the content of auth-routes not be accessible for users that are not authenticated, like in classic MPAs

Here I am placing a picture to make it easy to see what I mean.

[Searching for the content in the dev-console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbeVZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

A good way for authentication is to create an JWT for the user after he logged in. Whenever he navigates to the dashboard he loads the content via an REST Api and he authenticate with his token on that API to retreive some content.

In case somebody reach the secret page he wouldnt see any conent because he has no token to retreive some data from the database for example.

Comment: I am familiar with that concept but I'm not talking about protecting the response of a server or Route. I am concerned that ui-elements, which are part of the ditributed .js file are exposing certain information about the datastructures architecture.

For Example printing the id of a protected ressource does not mean that anybody can see the protected ressource. But someone can get information from the components served with the static .js-files about how data is beeing saved on the server side.

In MPAs that is not a Problem since every html response comes prerendered from the server.